# Function to subtract each element in a list

Tags: python, numpy, func

I’m attempting to make a function to subtract each element from a list in python, however, the first element must be `nan`.

This is my function:

```
def sub_vector(x):
  from numpy import nan
  
  y=[]
  for j, i in enumerate(range(len(x)-1)):
      z= np.nan
      if j == 0:
          y.append(z)
          
      else:
        val = x[i+1] - x[i]
        y.append(val)
  return y
```

The response should be such as:

```
zz = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
sub_vector(zz)  
[nan, 1, 1, 1 ,1]  
But this function is returning:  
[nan, 1, 1, 1]
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

```
from numpy import nan

def sub_vector(x):
    return [nan] + [x[i] - x[i - 1] for i in range(1, len(x))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) with `prepend=np.nan`

```
>>> np.diff(zz, prepend=np.nan)
array([nan,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

And your mistake is you don't need to check for the `0`. That is because the result of `enumerate(range(len(x)-1))` is `[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]`. So you are only iterating over four element, and your first iteration is getting skipped.

Drop the `if-else`:

```
def sub_vector(x):
  from numpy import nan

  y=[np.nan]
  for j, i in enumerate(range(len(x)-1)):
      val = x[i+1] - x[i]
      y.append(val)
  return y

>>> sub_vector(zz)
[nan, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Also, `enumerate(range(len(x)-1))` is non-pythonic and inefficient, you can do with `enumerate` alone, with the `start` parameter.

```
def sub_vector(x):
  from numpy import nan
  y=[]
  for j, _ in enumerate(x, start=-1):
      if j < 0:
          y.append(np.nan)
          continue
      val = x[j+1] - x[j]
      y.append(val)
  return y

>>> sub_vector(zz)
[nan, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

If you don't want to use `numpy`, you can use `list comprehension`:

```
>>> [(zz[i] - j) if i else np.nan for i, j in enumerate(zz)]
[nan, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Anyhow, if you are using `numpy`, `numpy.diff` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you are using if-else. remove that else condition and all works.
currently, it's skipping 1st execution of the loop iteration.

```
import numpy as np
def sub_vector(x):
  from numpy import nan

  y=[]
  for j, i in enumerate(range(len(x)-1)):
      z= np.nan
      if j == 0:
          y.append(z)
      val = x[i+1] - x[i]
      y.append(val)
  return y
print(sub_vector([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `numpy` at all:

```
>>> from operator import sub
>>> list(map(sub, x, [float('nan'), *x])))
[nan, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

This works because `x - float('nan') == float('nan')` for any `x` you can subtract `nan` from.

```
list(map(sub, x, [float('nan'), *x]))
  == (map(sub, [1,2,3,4,5], [float('nan'), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
  == [1-float('nan'), 2-1, 3-2, 4-3, 5-4]
```

Answer (score 0):

in you sub_vector function you don't iterate all the input vector ,you iterate len(x)-1 which means if your vector has 5 element the return vector will only contain 4 you can fix this by removing -1 in the range like this :

```
def sub_vector(x):
  from numpy import nan
  y=[]
  for j, i in enumerate(range(len(x))):
    z= np.nan
    if j == 0:
        y.append(z)
      
    else:
      val = x[i+1] - x[i]
      y.append(val)
  return y
```

you can directly do this

```
def sub_vector(x):
   return [np.nan if x==0 else 1 for x in range(len(x))]
```